# PyObjC - NSTableView with checkboxes mapping to Python throws class is not key value coding-compliant

Tags: objective-c, nstableview, nsarraycontroller, key-value-coding, pyobjc

I am building a Mac application using PyObjC. In Interface Builder I have a NSTableView. The Columns are filled with NSTextFieldCells and NSButtonCells.

I fill it with data using an array controller that itself is filled through a Python list of dicts. Instead of "Python dicts" I have also tried NSMutableDictionary. The keys representing NSTextFieldCells are filled with strings and the NSButtonCells with Booleans. For the latter I have also tried: 1/0, "Yes"/"No", and NSNumber.numberWithBool_ .

The stream of data from Python to the GUI works without a problem.

My problem is, that whenever I click on a checkbox it throws me:

```
(from bound object <NSTableColumn: 0x1067a52f0> identifier: (null)): [<__NSDictionaryI 0x10a604ed0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key checkb.
```

How can I get the states of the checkboxes back into my Python code?

Comment: Something in your code creates a immutable dictionary. -copy anywhere?

Comment: I'm not sure what could be causing this? What am I supposed to copy where?

Comment: Okay it works now and it was exactly what you described, which is awesome. Thank you so much.